# How does the regulatory body CAA link to aviation?

Tags: regulations, easa, caa-uk-regulations

How does the regulatory body CAA link to aviation?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE. I'm sorry, but I am not really sure how to answer you here. What do you know about the CAA? where have you looked and what exactly is unclear to you? the function that the CAA has? what do you mean with "link to aviation"?

Comment: There's a wikipedia page on the UK CAA here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Aviation_Authority_(United_Kingdom). Furthermore the CAA's page itself is pretty clear on what it does.

Answer (score 3):

Brief answer:
The CAA ensures that all flying in the country, be it small planes, or major airlines, are acting in accordance with policies, standards and aviation law. These standards and laws are written by ICAO (International Civil Aviation Organisation), and presuming you are referring to the UK CAA, standards and policies can also come from EASA (European Union Aviation Safety Agency) **[at the time of writing]**. Any differences in the standards, policies and laws from ICAO are listed in the CAA's [AIP](http://www.nats-uk.ead-it.com/public/index.php%3Foption=com_content&task=blogcategory&id=165&Itemid=3.html)

These standards, policies and laws which the CAA are responsible for regulating cover a wide range of areas: pilot's licenses to meteorological equipment and standards, rules of flying in the air (e.g. distance from cloud, filing flight plans) to aviation medicals, charts and NOTAMs  to compensation claims, drone safety at airports to aircraft design and parts, airport lights and signs to air traffic services available... [the list goes on...]

Basically, anything related to flying, the CAA will govern according with international rules written by ICAO (and EASA).